# When using foreign keys do you always have to join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm new to working with relational databases and have a sound understanding of how to query and join tables. My question today is a bit of a 2 part question because I don't really know how else to phrase it.

1. Generally, is it a good idea to break up tables with a lot of columns into multiple tables of "grouped data". From a query point, it should save time when certain data is not needed and it also makes it more readable.

For example, normally I would combine all of the following columns into one table and then query for all the data even if just using a few columns. I'm currently experimenting with the following database structure, the tables would all link via the `uid` column. :

**uploads**

- id
- name
- title
- description
- email
- date
- uid

**uploads_exif (everything but uid is optional)**

- id
- aperture
- iso
- shutter_speed
- camera
- uid

**uploads_social (everything but uid is optional)**

- id
- facebook
- twitter
- instagram
- flickr
- url
- uid

  2. If following the structure listed above, in order to query all the data am I required to use SQL JOINS or is there a way where I can simply query all tables. For example, if I need to get uploads, uploads_exif, and uploads_social in a single query is it possible to use another function to simply query all of them without using a JOIN or is using a JOIN the correct way to go about doing this.

Any help would be greatly appriciated, thanks!

Comment: First, if the table is a unity, and all the data you are storing there is coherent it's not a good idea to split the table into multiple tables. Just query with a good select naming the columns you want to query. Second, you should read about normal forms, that will help you a lot. Third, there are a lots of ways to query without joins, it just happend that joins are better in performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is coherent its not a good idea Split the table into multiple tables"

Comment: If the data is about the same thing, and it is strongly related the it should be on the same table

Comment: @Nambu14 The data is essentially about the same thing but the required data is stored in the `uploads` table, the other two tables have data that is mostly optional except the `uid`. Would it still be a better option performance wise to store everything in one table even though a lot of the data can be null?

Comment: 1) The columns of a table should relate to the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.  That's basically [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to the 3rd normal form.  2) The reason for foreign keys is to perform joins.  Relational databases perform joins very efficiently, so joins are what you code.

Comment: Like anything in engineering, it depends on the context. One thing is speaking about the design and the good practices and another one is about performance. To achive good performance the DBAs tend to denormalize databases, especially in Data Warehouse environment. If yours is a transactional DB then I always recommend to stick to good practices and principles, while performance issues are not critical.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc "The reason for foreign keys is to perform joins." is misleading. Any two tables can be meaningfully joined. There is a FK when some columns of a first table'a CK contain only values from some columns of a second table's CK. Declaring that to the DBMS helps it to keep out invalid states and to optimize. So the reason for *declaring* FKs *includes* performing joins *better*. What FKs there are arise from what you decided to record in tables, some of which might be from normalizing earlier designs.

Comment: What does "get uploads, uploads_exif, and uploads_social in a single query" mean? If you want rows that have subrows that apear in uploads, uploads_exif, and uploads_social, that is what the join of those three is *defined* to return. You seem to be *fear* joins. Relational DBMSs exists because *it is productive* if you intend to query arbitrarily to organize data in tables (preferably normalized to 5NF). Using a join is just  the way that you query for rows having a subrow in one table "and" in another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many answers to "grouping of columns".  Your question points out two cases; I think they are instructive:

`uploads_exif` --

- 1:1 with main table (`uploads`).  So, the first inclination is to say "don't split", but...
- Many pictures do not have exif, and the exif is bulky, and it is not needed for all queries, so it *does* make sense to split it into a separate table.
- Get rid of `id`, since `uid` is unique, it can be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (This will make the `JOIN` more efficient.)

`uploads_social` --

- 1:1 with main table (`uploads`).  So, the first inclination is to say "don't split", but...
- That's really an "array" of things.  Do not splay an array across columns.
- If the columns are just true/false flags, then consider using a `SET`. (And put it in the main table.)
- If the columns are urls (or similar stuff) then do a 1:many (sort of):

Change to

```
CREATE TABLE uploads_social (
    uid ...,
    which ENUM('facebook', 'twitter', ...),
    url ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(uid, which)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

(An aside) When Normalizing, don't over-normalize.  Do not normalize dates, floats, or other 'continuous' values.

Why have both `id` and `uid` in `uploads`?  *Probably* you should get rid of `id` and promote `uid` to `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is actually a lot more helpful than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

First you should try to study [**Third Normal Form**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

The number the columns isnt the main factor, the important is try to avoid repetition so maintenance become easier.

For example if you have a table

```
employee: [id, first_name, last_name]
```

You wont need to split it that into two tables, ok this is extreme but you get the idea.

```
employee_first: [id, first_name]
employee_last: [id, last_name]
```

The other case is avoid repeat data.

if you have a field `favorite_fruit` instead of using a text field you create a fk table and save integers.

```
   favorite_fruit      favorite_fruit       id  fruit
   orange                 1                  1  orange                 
   orange                 1                  2  apple
   apple          ==>     2                  3  pineapple
   pineapple              3
```

Save space and is easy to edit, for example if you want change `orage` to `orange juice` only need replace one.

Not sure what is your case, but for example if you have different type of `upload` you can have a master table `upload` with `type_id` and each type can have a separated table for details.

```
    UPLOAD               |     table: [UPLOAD TYPE1]                     
 upload_id  type_id      | upload_id  [fields unique for type1]  
    xxxx      1      ==> |   xxxxx    ooooooo                 
    yyyy      2          |===================================== 
                         |     table: [UPLOAD TYPE2]
                         | upload_id [fields unique for type2]
                         | yyyyy     oooooooo
```

Another example is employee adress.

istead of add multiple field for `building, street, zip code` you create three tables

```
   employee: employee_id
   adress:  address_id, building, street, zip code
   employee_adress: employee_id, adress_id.
```

That way one employee can have multiple address just adding a separated entity `address` and assign to `employee` using `employee_adress`

Comment: So really in my application, it seems that nothing is going to be changing, it's all user generated content. The general idea is to use normalization when content can be updated for multiple rows, not used to speed up performance?

Comment: Seem you dont need it, but again study 3rd normal form. I add other examples.

Comment: Since I'm just learning normalization and joins, would this be a good time to test it out? Would there be any negative impacts on my application?

Comment: No negative impact, important is you test it using `EXPLAIN PLAN` and create proper `INDEX`